# Setting ImageViews side by side inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I was trying to get two images side by side inside my LinearLayout. I tried setting my layout weight to 1 as suggested by many other posts I saw here for both views but to no avail. The imageViews in question are the ones with the ID rainfall and wind. What am I doing wrong here? I even tried wrapping them inside a relative layout and it did not work. This is what they look like with the code below: I just want the umbrellas to be side by side instead of one being slightly below the other one? Any ideas?
[image]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="location"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/condition"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtCondition"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maxMin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/highTemp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wind"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_umbrella"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="start"  />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rainfall"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_umbrella"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secDay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/weekHigh"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put them inside a LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wind"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_umbrella"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"  />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rainfall"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_umbrella"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks but I had to change layout_orientation to orientation for the nested LinearLayout.

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to close if your question is solved.